# Problemas sincronizando la base de datos en Django

Tags: django, base-de-datos

Estoy creando un app en Django y cuando trato de ejecutar "makemigrations" me sale el siguiente error

```
> (env) C:\Users\Jorge Ceron\env\Scripts\lgsbeta>python manage.py
> makemigrations Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py",
> line 22, in <module>
>     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "C:\Users\JORGEC~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.
> py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
>     utility.execute()   File "C:\Users\JORGEC~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.
> py", line 341, in execute
>     django.setup()   File "C:\Users\JORGEC~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27,
> in  setup
>     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File "C:\Users\JORGEC~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py",
> line 1 08, in populate
>     app_config.import_models(all_models)   File "C:\Users\JORGEC~1\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line
> 199 , in import_models
>     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)   File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
>     __import__ (name)   File "C:\Users\Jorge Ceron\env\Scripts\lgsbeta\lgsbeta1\models.py", line 5, in  <module>
>     class Expansion(models.Model):   File "C:\Users\Jorge Ceron\env\Scripts\lgsbeta\lgsbeta1\models.py", line 6, in  Expansion
>     Nombre_exp = models.Charfield(max_length=30) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Charfield'
```

Al checar [la documentacion de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---fake-initial) me comenta que hay que hacer migraciones falsas y que si tenemos migraciones duplicadas no va a poder ejecutarse.

He leido que hay que aplicar y desaplicar las migraciones, pero no me termina de quedar claro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

es un error tipográfico! CharField(). No Charfield.

Comment: Es correcto, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

El error te Dice que el módulo de models de django no cuenta con el atributo `Charfield` por lo que te Dice que hay algo malo... La corrección es usar `CharField` que como vea tiene la **'F'** en mayúscula... Esto solucionará tu problema